# Tkinter Entry Not Updating

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import datetime
import os

root = Tk()
root.title("To-do List")
root.geometry("400x600")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
# Balance
global be
bet = settings_main_canvas.create_text(110, 165, text="Balance: ", font="Helvetica 14") # Balance Entry Text
be = Entry(root, width=20, font="Helvetica 10", borderwidth=2, bg="#f0f0f0") # Balance Entry
be.insert(0, "Amount in USD")
settings_main_canvas.create_window(170, 165, window=be, anchor=W)



# Text
global acc_name
global balance
global progress_bar_tasks
acc_name = sidebar_canvas.create_text(65, 18, text=ane.get(), font="TimesNewRoman 10 bold", anchor=NW)
balance = sidebar_canvas.create_text(65, 35, text=be.get() + "$", font="TimesNewRoman 8", anchor=NW)
progress_bar_tasks = sidebar_canvas.create_text(180, 30, text="{} / {} Complete".format(len(inbox_finished_tasks), len(inbox_tasks_num)), font="TimesNewRoman 9", anchor=NW)
root.mainloop()
```

I don't know why but when I print `be.get()` it always returns the value that I inserted, even though I changed the text in the entry

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: You're calling `.get()` about a millisecond after creating the entry widget.

Comment: We had virtually this same question earlier today.  You must learn about event-driven programming.  When you call these "create" functions, nothing gets drawn.  All that does is send messages requesting that the controls get created.  Those messages will all pile up until up call `root.mainloop`.  Only at that point are the messages dispatched, and your control drawn.  You cannot read the users input until they tell you it is ready, usually by clicking a button.  You add a callback to handle the click event and fetch the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is, before you can edit the text in the entry, `balance` already is created and does not update constantly. So the text in `balance` doesn’t update.

### **EDIT**:

Here's what you can do(Feel free to edit the names of variables, customize them and edit the function):

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#Defining the update label function
def updateLbl():
    lbl.config(text=enter.get())

    root.after(1000, updateLbl)

enter = Entry(root)
enter.pack()
enter.insert(0, "text")

lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack()

#calling the function
updateLbl()

root.after(1000, updateLbl)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't get it, so what do I change?

Comment: Answer edited @MarkGeorge

Comment: Umm, I have an issue,, `canvas.create_text()` doesn't have .config

Comment: @MarkGeorge , can you move the label and entry to the root window instead of the canvas? If you can, try that and you will not need `canvas.create_text()`

Comment: well, then what's the point of the canvas, I want to group them in one place, so I can say delete all one time

Comment: If you want to group them, no draw any shapes etc. then you can use frames